# Scroll bar to get all rows value from table WedDriver Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get all row value from the table, the problem is that I only can get the first 10 row in scripts (actually I have more 200 rows), after I scroll the bar of the table, I can get other 10 rows value, I want to know how I can do this in script?
I guess I should use scrollIntoView or scrollBy something, but didn't know the detail. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to one WebElement you can use this:

```
public static void scrollToElement(WebElement we){
    Coordinates coordinate = ((Locatable)we).getCoordinates(); 
    coordinate.onPage(); 
    coordinate.inViewPort();
}
```